# How to have a draggable text on a canvas?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am working on a paint application , i can set the text anywhere on a canvas but once i set the text , text is not draggable. I want to drag and then drop the text anywhere i want. How can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

If you work with canvas you need to implement that by your own. You need to store the dimensions and the position, than you can calculate if a touch event is on the text or not.

Also keep in mind that you need a copy of the backgoround without the text